# Heroku Deploy - Application Error (Ruby On Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, github

This is my issue, when I deploy to heroku my app, the app crashes, this is the log... I'm newbie on this, please help me, thanks.

```
dc00.jpg" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=a0911e3d-1245-4ef6-8bc4-

09d7a9cb4233
 fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=56ms status=200 bytes=11500
67
2016-08-18T20:27:17.601703+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/categorias/icoworking-

912ecd6158afcd41add098ab30f838e73fa80b4126e962

7bf5e6f19c
9f262770.jpg" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=00cdd720-46d3-448f-9d3a-4f4f46c8
dd70 fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 

connect=1ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=1
30807
2016-08-18T20:27:17.564722+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/categorias/ichristmas-

84ae823bf67e9ccf7206ed9e9c5a211587d21891fd5000

019a377faf
ce23c563.jpg" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=f2cd71f6-98fb-46de-a8d8-70cbf388
640e fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 

connect=1ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=6
9501
2016-08-18T20:27:17.589235+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/categorias/ikids-

905c89db928463049caf8fae349700b85e507735bba4c8

1af08ce6e85ecbb
8de.jpg" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=46c4ff75-3065-4444-b243-

a33f0f519a54
fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=37ms status=200 bytes=107271
4
2016-08-18T20:27:17.564268+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/categorias/ihome-

1faadfb5c6e8f7df0a9dc152fb4ec76506bb11ad2b3f51

60ae1d2ad84fc51
971.jpg" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=c329c864-3aca-487a-868e-

1e1820855446
fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=15ms status=200 bytes=129305

2016-08-18T20:27:19.224769+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/equipo/Vane-

9d134ec975589d5700841b0aa81263c2af3d05b74b1787

34710bd86628ef2637.j
pg" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=06068614-c680-41d2-b728-

5b5cf65e556a fwd="
190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=5ms status=200 bytes=21314
2016-08-18T20:27:19.361841+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/equipo/Marita-

1b731eb21007ad3420cc67780ad27a37f326e101334282

2483b73863a97f743d
.jpg" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=6b02c2cc-d528-4dd8-a4de-

bd4e00c59e88 fwd
="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=4ms status=200 bytes=22990
2016-08-18T20:27:20.014109+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/auspiciadores/fablab-

2aae69f72a506dd6b2efdec2e2c6f0690601277a1ff0a3

254c71542a0
c930a3c.png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=2ee02ee4-c949-479b-bb1b-09e688dc6
559 fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 

connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=893
45
2016-08-18T20:27:20.210298+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/auspiciadores/cisanmarcos-

422b6b8ac92aad0196c28a93e489a39e2111b8e56476ca

730996
7a5f2b7e9ae9.png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=e5768ccf-d136-45c1-ab3c-ab70
85afa333 fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 

connect=1ms service=87ms status=200 byt
es=171763
2016-08-18T20:27:20.148749+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/auspiciadores/starupperu-

535135f2c052053030a529e0f0f3be267a1e4906ab0ab5

b5e6852
3a087b40c2e.png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=a0b11bbd-7cf1-43e3-91b5-19583
764c482 fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 

connect=1ms service=58ms status=200 byte
s=7645
2016-08-18T20:27:20.369598+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/auspiciadores/equipu-

17be8860c464126f698a61a9d30029f993e64571141049

b724ce554e8
a057bf1.png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=de5f4ba8-ee1a-4070-8407-585a672d6
6c6 fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 

connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=112
18
2016-08-18T20:27:20.598349+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/auspiciadores/fablabtecsup-

286ab7fa9ea90f9c9ac826a7990de73950da357a5105c7

9198a
b711dabeef71c.png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=4d2531e3-a332-418d-9bc0-ee8
6f6a442df fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 

connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 byt
es=22603
2016-08-18T20:27:21.118011+00:00 app[web.1]:   

Refinery::Blog::Post Load (1.2ms)
  SELECT "refinery_blog_posts".* FROM 

"refinery_blog_posts" INNER JOIN "refinery
_blog_post_translations" ON 

"refinery_blog_post_translations"."refinery_bl

og_pos
t_id" = "refinery_blog_posts"."id" WHERE 

("refinery_blog_posts"."published_at" <
 '2016-08-18 20:27:21.112258') AND 

"refinery_blog_posts"."draft" = $1 AND "refin
ery_blog_post_translations"."locale" = 'es'  

ORDER BY published_at DESC  [["draf
t", "f"]]
2016-08-18T20:27:21.105854+00:00 app[web.1]:   

Parameters: {"locale"=>:es}
2016-08-18T20:27:21.123053+00:00 app[web.1]:   

Refinery::Authentication::Devise:
:Role Load (1.1ms)  SELECT 

"refinery_authentication_devise_roles".* FROM 

"refine
ry_authentication_devise_roles" INNER JOIN 

"refinery_authentication_devise_roles
_users" ON 

"refinery_authentication_devise_roles"."id" = 

"refinery_authenticatio
n_devise_roles_users"."role_id" WHERE 

"refinery_authentication_devise_roles_user
s"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 3]]
2016-08-18T20:27:21.127220+00:00 app[web.1]:   

Refinery::Page::Translation Load
(1.1ms)  SELECT "refinery_page_translations".* 

FROM "refinery_page_translations"
 WHERE 

"refinery_page_translations"."refinery_page_id

" = $1  [["refinery_page_id
", 1]]
2016-08-18T20:27:21.105818+00:00 app[web.1]: 

Processing by Refinery::PagesContro
ller#home as HTML
2016-08-18T20:27:21.136676+00:00 app[web.1]:   

Rendered refinery/_head.html.erb
(5.5ms)
2016-08-18T20:27:21.142223+00:00 app[web.1]:   

Rendered refinery/_footer.html.er
b (1.8ms)
2016-08-18T20:27:21.120276+00:00 app[web.1]:   

Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/bundler/gems/refinerycms-

3af4b957998b/core/app/views/refinery/_html_tag

.html.er
b (0.1ms)
2016-08-18T20:27:21.142879+00:00 app[web.1]: 

Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 25
.0ms | ActiveRecord: 6.8ms)
2016-08-18T20:27:21.103471+00:00 app[web.1]: 

Started GET "/" for 190.234.105.38
at 2016-08-18 20:27:21 +0000
2016-08-18T20:27:21.111413+00:00 app[web.1]:   

Refinery::Page Load (1.1ms)  SELE
CT  "refinery_pages".* FROM "refinery_pages" 

WHERE "refinery_pages"."link_url" =
 $1 LIMIT 1  [["link_url", "/"]]
2016-08-18T20:27:21.130923+00:00 app[web.1]:   

Rendered refinery/_site_bar.html.
erb (10.5ms)
2016-08-18T20:27:21.119939+00:00 app[web.1]:   

Rendered refinery/pages/home.html
.erb within layouts/application (6.2ms)
2016-08-18T20:27:21.108503+00:00 app[web.1]:   

Refinery::Authentication::Devise:
:User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  

"refinery_authentication_devise_users".* FROM 

"refin
ery_authentication_devise_users" WHERE 

"refinery_authentication_devise_users"."i
d" = $1  ORDER BY 

"refinery_authentication_devise_users"."id" 

ASC LIMIT 1  [["id
", 3]]
2016-08-18T20:27:21.134447+00:00 app[web.1]:   

SeoMetum Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "s
eo_meta".* FROM "seo_meta" WHERE 

"seo_meta"."seo_meta_type" = $1 AND 

"seo_meta".
"seo_meta_id" IS NULL  ORDER BY 

"seo_meta"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  

[["seo_meta_type",
"Refinery::Page::Translation"]]
2016-08-18T20:27:21.142503+00:00 app[web.1]:   

Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/bundler/gems/refinerycms-

3af4b957998b/core/app/views/refinery/_javascri

pts.html
.erb (0.1ms)
2016-08-18T20:27:21.136505+00:00 app[web.1]:   

Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/bundler/gems/refinerycms-

3af4b957998b/core/app/views/refinery/_google_a

nalytics
.html.erb (0.6ms)
2016-08-18T20:27:21.140257+00:00 app[web.1]:   

Rendered refinery/_header.html.er
b (3.2ms)
2016-08-18T20:27:21.150248+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" hos
t=www.ifurniture.pe request_id=30c447d8-f0e0-

4138-a16e-08ab889db55e fwd="190.234
.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=45ms 

status=200 bytes=22270
2016-08-18T20:27:21.183937+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/dev-logo-

eaf505bf5fde50bde6052f8eb86e2f0d02e7e2697b18e9

457235643659395afc.png"
 host=www.ifurniture.pe request_id=4d67a409-

b2e9-4e43-addc-fedcf4ad5f9c fwd="190
.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms 

service=9ms status=200 bytes=1845
2016-08-18T20:27:21.722798+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/dev-logo-

eaf505bf5fde50bde6052f8eb86e2f0d02e7e2697b18e9

457235643659395afc.png"
 host=www.ifurniture.pe request_id=67612811-

c616-4283-a78f-c5c59cea5348 fwd="190
.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=5ms status=206 bytes=264
2016-08-18T20:27:21.712333+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/categorias/ilamps-

b27d0f0fac01c9ff3a1bd2459e750beace8316468ba205

739632c60dabd1
dc00.jpg" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=d0ff6e9f-03ff-478a-94ce-

ce53f69b3b3c
 fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=4ms status=206 bytes=272
2016-08-18T20:27:21.682001+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/background-image-

c26087f21cdbf01a4d701222d49b3f914184acb8747572

cb905568ee5612e
191.jpg" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=265168dd-4660-44ff-a9bc-

9c1367ac8ce5
fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=3ms status=206 bytes=271
2016-08-18T20:27:21.721978+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/auspiciadores/cisanmarcos-

422b6b8ac92aad0196c28a93e489a39e2111b8e56476ca

730996
7a5f2b7e9ae9.png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=34b87dfc-c2ec-42b4-ac73-b7c8
812466d6 fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 

connect=1ms service=4ms status=206 byte
s=270
2016-08-18T20:27:21.738227+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/categorias/ikids-

905c89db928463049caf8fae349700b85e507735bba4c8

1af08ce6e85ecbb
8de.jpg" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=79e636a8-37c8-43b2-b1f8-

369b722d1a47
fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms 

service=8ms status=206 bytes=272
2016-08-18T20:27:21.980292+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/background-image-

c26087f21cdbf01a4d701222d49b3f914184acb8747572

cb905568ee5612e
191.jpg" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=42638e9e-6f76-4960-9e7b-

5d1d072abdcb
fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=15ms status=206 bytes=282361

2016-08-18T20:27:22.050192+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/categorias/ikids-

905c89db928463049caf8fae349700b85e507735bba4c8

1af08ce6e85ecbb
8de.jpg" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=d72665a4-254d-4240-81cd-

04cea920f4c8
fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=22ms status=206 bytes=510779

2016-08-18T20:27:21.974721+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/auspiciadores/cisanmarcos-

422b6b8ac92aad0196c28a93e489a39e2111b8e56476ca

730996
7a5f2b7e9ae9.png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=e23d2a23-add6-401d-a9de-172d
d706feaf fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 

connect=1ms service=9ms status=206 byte
s=68266
2016-08-18T20:27:21.994500+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/dev-logo-

eaf505bf5fde50bde6052f8eb86e2f0d02e7e2697b18e9

457235643659395afc.png"
 host=www.ifurniture.pe request_id=a3523659-

f287-4d0b-bd7d-4619e452d91b fwd="190
.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=9ms 

service=12ms status=206 bytes=671
2016-08-18T20:27:22.039575+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/categorias/ilamps-

b27d0f0fac01c9ff3a1bd2459e750beace8316468ba205

739632c60dabd1
dc00.jpg" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=3ceef880-14b6-4363-b862-

7cc571767058
 fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=21ms status=206 bytes=57088
8
2016-08-18T20:27:22.292231+00:00 app[web.1]: 

Started GET "/assets/proceso-backgr
ound.jpg" for 190.234.105.38 at 2016-08-18 

20:27:22 +0000
2016-08-18T20:27:22.585286+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/proceso-background.jpg" 

host=www.ifurniture.pe request_id=58526a33-

96a2-4c82-8
0c9-c05a5ae8f20c fwd="190.234.105.38" 

dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=293ms statu
s=200 bytes=527591
2016-08-18T20:27:22.785432+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/arrow.png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=70174db3-982f-48bb-ae56-ed87d9b63
d5b fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 

connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=524
2
2016-08-18T20:27:22.777275+00:00 app[web.1]: 

Started GET "/assets/arrow.png" for
 190.234.105.38 at 2016-08-18 20:27:22 +0000
2016-08-18T20:27:23.029608+00:00 app[web.1]: 

Started GET "/assets/equipo-backgro
und.jpg" for 190.234.105.38 at 2016-08-18 

20:27:23 +0000
2016-08-18T20:27:23.054815+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/equipo-background.jpg" 

host=www.ifurniture.pe request_id=1ce1952d-

3b9f-4092-a0
2f-dffd0fb766ec fwd="190.234.105.38" 

dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=
200 bytes=470808
2016-08-18T20:27:24.573881+00:00 app[web.1]: 

Started GET "/assets/auspiciadores-
background.jpg" for 190.234.105.38 at 2016-08

-18 20:27:24 +0000
2016-08-18T20:27:24.594677+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/auspiciadores-background.jpg" 

host=www.ifurniture.pe request_id=0857fa15-

4ae6-
4bda-9570-0edcaf843631 fwd="190.234.105.38" 

dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20ms
status=200 bytes=297134
2016-08-18T20:27:25.382392+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/auspiciadores/dev-

fa40e7b96a93e38c56864cec44f26a06c28965df4ed516

efe86142a48507
c56b.png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=fff05167-b391-468e-8c1f-

13866273c107
 fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=3ms status=200 bytes=10874
2016-08-18T20:27:25.544019+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/auspiciadores/utec-

f400f729cea769beeef7fa57053094bffe1b6ecb0715d5

84fcc5974e5dc
8f370.png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=ff0be48d-d0ea-467c-a69a-db00768d9ef
e fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=5ms status=200 bytes=17792

2016-08-18T20:27:25.787811+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/auspiciadores/starscamp-

f3d82983a999c905bd8cb50f25045f2a2e41b067edc5dc

bd467f78
38163440a7.png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=59f30aa9-0e8b-4206-8656-98aa68
18c157 fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 

connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=
15643
2016-08-18T20:27:26.017702+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/ifurniture-logo2-

bedd7a8c5532a67f479891e9e867aab2d88757565e62c4

9a8ce7cd5d7f428
fdd.png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=14e1bed9-2a40-420f-853f-

259da441ddda
fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=3ms status=200 bytes=10730
2016-08-18T20:27:26.246864+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/phone-

b003ee5f15577917d022c6faaad5042c3994459d7a9dd4

35f81f211dbf3fc0a2.png" ho
st=www.ifurniture.pe request_id=53dea1b6-

fadd-4060-ac70-15c93c16552d fwd="190.23
4.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms 

status=200 bytes=755
2016-08-18T20:27:26.485881+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/social/facebook-

4da21b4563ab36eb423321faa852df769a17e27a6ed544

d495857188ee2e13
03.png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=da27d119-b3fd-4486-b375-

91820ae1c810 f
wd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=3ms status=200 bytes=1800
2016-08-18T20:27:26.682556+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/social/twitter-

b579e0126345914ecf508d48efa1641bf966bcfea125e3

d246d00bc2b86fc8b
a.png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=7abfb690-0dbe-41fa-8c0d-

c817e2c64ef0 fw
d="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=3ms status=200 bytes=1948
2016-08-18T20:27:26.811899+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/social/instagram-

d050d98efcc6d3510ae76edb1cb57ec11cd127cd4beb06

cf0f07693092eb1
5b5.png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=d4957bee-b516-4eb9-92cd-

961ebb8f3752
fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=4ms status=200 bytes=2201
2016-08-18T20:27:27.050430+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/social/youtube-

bdf0b2319be6324d6245f7c6db1d63ffabcb78cf315492

36f29c5dc04a960aa
1.png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=46228d3a-d939-4030-9170-

ad446ac7c8fb fw
d="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=5ms status=200 bytes=2268
2016-08-18T20:27:27.004647+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/social/vimeo-

d2b868893c90cdc023e29f5601766614ad021a57aebae8

0aa0faf17967551e21.
png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=991c392a-77fd-408c-8b98-

a255f3827008 fwd=
"190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=3ms status=200 bytes=2033
2016-08-18T20:27:26.872535+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/social/pinterest-

6aff9931162f787382d4047d59046045db0d08dd2741dd

67bc28c1015cde9
892.png" host=www.ifurniture.pe 

request_id=7db8b710-52b9-4163-8a2c-

017a7260be1a
fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 

service=3ms status=200 bytes=2014
2016-08-18T21:01:19.058843+00:00 heroku

[web.1]: Idling
2016-08-18T21:01:19.059312+00:00 heroku

[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2016-08-18T21:01:21.774103+00:00 heroku

[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGT
ERM
2016-08-18T21:01:22.375459+00:00 app[web.1]:   

 /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/
2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2016-08-18T21:01:22.375464+00:00 app[web.1]:   

 /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/
2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2016-08-18T21:01:22.375463+00:00 app[web.1]:   

 /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/
2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in 

start'
2016-08-18T21:01:22.375467+00:00 app[web.1]:   

 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-

4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:

in `tap'
2016-08-18T21:01:22.375449+00:00 app[web.1]: 

[2016-08-18 21:01:22] FATAL SignalE
xception: SIGTERM
2016-08-18T21:01:22.375467+00:00 app[web.1]:   

 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-

4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:

in `block in server'
2016-08-18T21:01:22.375468+00:00 app[web.1]:   

 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-

4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:

in `server'
2016-08-18T21:01:22.375463+00:00 app[web.1]:   

 /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/
2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2016-08-18T21:01:22.375466+00:00 app[web.1]:   

 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-

4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in 

`start'
2016-08-18T21:01:22.375465+00:00 app[web.1]:   

 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in 

`start'
2016-08-18T21:01:22.375465+00:00 app[web.1]:   

 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/rack-

1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2016-08-18T21:01:22.375469+00:00 app[web.1]:   

 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-

4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:

in `run_command!'
2016-08-18T21:01:22.375470+00:00 app[web.1]:   

 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in 

`<top (required)>'
2016-08-18T21:01:22.375471+00:00 app[web.1]:   

 bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2016-08-18T21:01:22.375471+00:00 app[web.1]:   

 bin/rails:8:in `require'
2016-08-18T21:01:22.375928+00:00 app[web.1]: 

[2016-08-18 21:01:22] INFO  going t
o shutdown ...
2016-08-18T21:01:22.376280+00:00 app[web.1]: 

[2016-08-18 21:01:22] INFO  WEBrick
::HTTPServer#start done.
2016-08-18T21:01:22.376749+00:00 app[web.1]: 

Exiting
2016-08-18T21:01:22.587342+00:00 heroku

[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-08-18T21:13:41.133875+00:00 heroku[slug-

compiler]: Slug compilation started

2016-08-18T21:13:40.903288+00:00 heroku[api]: 

Deploy 8f24e0b by hola@ifurniture.
pe
2016-08-18T21:13:41.133883+00:00 heroku[slug-

compiler]: Slug compilation finishe
d
2016-08-18T21:13:40.903331+00:00 heroku[api]: 

Release v48 created by hola@ifurni
ture.pe
2016-08-18T21:13:41.165635+00:00 heroku

[web.1]: State changed from down to start
ing
2016-08-18T21:13:47.336169+00:00 heroku

[web.1]: Starting process with command `p
uma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-

development}`
2016-08-18T21:13:49.471199+00:00 app[web.1]: 

bash: puma: command not found
2016-08-18T21:13:49.547875+00:00 heroku

[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-08-18T21:13:49.569676+00:00 heroku

[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-08-18T21:13:49.570796+00:00 heroku

[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2016-08-18T21:13:54.546403+00:00 heroku

[web.1]: Starting process with command `p
uma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-

development}`
2016-08-18T21:13:56.163634+00:00 app[web.1]: 

bash: puma: command not found
2016-08-18T21:13:56.216786+00:00 heroku

[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-08-18T21:13:56.229516+00:00 heroku

[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-08-18T21:13:57.322769+00:00 heroku

[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" 

host=www.ifurniture.pe request_id=33345f95-

9eeb-411c-8
76d-db4caec60f41 fwd="190.234.105.38" dyno= 

connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I ran the CMD

```
heroku run rake db:create

heroku run rake db:migrate

heroku run rake db:seed
```

I too try the CMD

```
heroku ps:scale web=0
```

I waited 5 minutes, and run CMD

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

That don't works so, i run the CMD

```
heroku restart
```

But the issue continue and I can't get my webpage working. I'll watching for yours answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot in that log but this error sticks out

```
bash: puma: command not found
```

Do you have `puma` in your `Gemfile`? Try adding `gem 'puma'` to your `Gemfile`.

Comment: In which group I add the gem ?.

Comment: You would probably add it to production but just to make sure you can get it working don't add it to a group so it will work in all environments.